# Is it possible to iterate over a list of objects and print/return the name of each object (not what it refers to)?

Tags: python, list, loops, object

I have a list of fit models:

`model_list = [xgboost_1, xgboost_2, random_forest_1, random_forest_2 ...]`

I want to iterate over them and populate a `results` dataframe with their prediction output metrics:

`results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['models', 'fpr', 'tpr', 'auc'])`

I want the `models` column in `results` to populate with `xgboost_1`, `xgboost_2`, etc. by name.

I can populate the df with all the metrics, but I'm having trouble with the `models` col.

Comment: No, names refer to values unidirectionally. You cannot go from value to name. Use a better datastructure, such as a dict.

Comment: Generally, if your code relies on variables' names, then you're doing something wrong or inefficiently. Code should never rely on the names of variables. Maybe store the variables in a `dict`, with the dict keys being the same as the variables' names?

Comment: Yes, I'll have to use a dictionary it seems. The code itself doesn't rely on the names per se. I'm just using them to the create visualizations, which is why I want to retain them.